# Why is "por" prefered to "para" in the example within?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, preposiciones

From Shakira's *Suerte*:

> Yo puedo escalar los Andes solo
>
> Por ir a contar tus lunares

Why is *por* preferable to *para* in this case. If one translation of *para* is roughly "for the purpose of", then doesn't "for the purpose of counting your moles" make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have misunderstood the meaning of the sentence. The sentence is not saying that he would climb the Andes for the purpose of counting her moles, but that counting her moles is his motivation for climbing.

Comment: Which are semantically pretty much the same. Purpose and motivation at least in that sentence, do mean equivalent things.

Comment: In sentences like this, "por" means more of "due to" / "as a result of" / "because of".  _para_ is "in order that", "with the goal of".  When describing rationales, por will always refer to the past, and para to the future:

_Lo hice por no tener dinero_ — I did an action, and I was already out of money (the lack thereof being the impetus to my action.
_Lo hice para no tener dinero_ - I did the action while I had money, but my goal was to get rid of my money.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would make more sense and be more grammatically correct *para* in this case, but *por* is not wrong either, and song lyrics are the place to take this kind of liberties.